# In DB2 how keyword like LENGTH of SYSCAT.COLUMNS table can be used along with CONCAT in SQL Script to double the length of VARCHAR columns

Tags: sql, select, db2, conditional-statements

In My below SQL LENGTH is a keyword and also  a column name in table SYSCAT.COLUMNS. How can I correct below Query. I am getting exception

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' CONCAT TABNAME CONCAT ' ALTER COLUMN ' CONCAT  COLNAME CONCAT ' SET DATA TYPE ' CONCAT TYPENAME CONCAT '('
CONCAT LENGTH CONCAT ');'
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA= 'ABC' AND TYPENAME = 'VARCHAR' AND TABNAME = 'XYZ';
```

Exception:-

```
[Error] Script lines: 1-4 --------------------------
 DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -440, SQLSTATE: 42884, SQLERRMC: CONCAT;FUNCTION
 Message: No authorized routine named "CONCAT" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.
```

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows versions prior to 9.7, DB2 enforced strong typing.  So you can't concatenate a VARCHAR and an INTEGER without first casting the INTEGER to a string.

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' CONCAT TABNAME 
    CONCAT ' ALTER COLUMN ' CONCAT  COLNAME 
    CONCAT ' SET DATA TYPE ' CONCAT TYPENAME 
    CONCAT '(' CONCAT char(LENGTH) CONCAT ');'
FROM 
    SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABSCHEMA= 'ABC' 
    AND TYPENAME = 'VARCHAR' 
    AND TABNAME = 'XYZ';
```

In DB2 9.7, IBM added implicit casting, so your query will work as written.

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT (||) works on strings. I would suspect that LENGTH is not a string

Try casting them as strings (char) : char(LENGTH) instead of LENGTH

Now your Query looks like:-
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' CONCAT TABNAME CONCAT ' ALTER COLUMN ' CONCAT COLNAME CONCAT ' SET DATA TYPE ' CONCAT TYPENAME CONCAT '(' CONCAT CHAR (LENGTH) CONCAT ');' FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA= 'ABC' AND TYPENAME = 'VARCHAR' AND TABNAME = 'XYZ';